# Joining on 3 csv files

Tags: sql, excel, vba, csv, join

I need to retrieve data from 3 different CSV files (Adres.CSV, ID.CSV and Regios.CSV) and combine this in an Excel table.

This SQL statement works fine,

```
StrSQL = "SELECT ID.[ID], Adres.[Naam], Adres.[Adres], Adres.[Plaats] " _
         & "FROM Adres.CSV Adres INNER JOIN ID.CSV ID ON Adres.[Naam] = ID.[Naam];"
```

as well as

```
StrSQL = "SELECT Adres.[Naam], Adres.[Adres], Adres.[Plaats], Regio.[Regio] " _
         & "FROM Adres.CSV Adres INNER JOIN Regios.CSV Regio ON Adres.[Plaats] = Regio.[Plaats];"
```

but when I combine them to

```
StrSQL = "SELECT ID.[ID], Adres.[Naam], Adres.[Adres], Adres.[Plaats], Regio.[Regio] " _
         & "FROM Adres.CSV Adres " _
         & "INNER JOIN Regios.CSV Regio ON Adres.[Plaats] = Regio.[Plaats]" _
         & "INNER JOIN ID.CSV ID ON Adres.[Naam] = ID.[Naam];"
```

I get an error message that an operator is missing.

What am I overlooking?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are two issues here:

1. You are missing a space between the 3rd and 4th lines.
2. JET/ACE SQL requires you to use parentheses when doing multiple joins.

This should fix the sql error you are seeing:

```
StrSQL = "SELECT ID.[ID], Adres.[Naam], Adres.[Adres], Adres.[Plaats], Regio.[Regio] " _
         & "FROM (Adres.CSV Adres " _
         & "INNER JOIN Regios.CSV Regio ON Adres.[Plaats] = Regio.[Plaats]) " _
         & "INNER JOIN ID.CSV ID ON Adres.[Naam] = ID.[Naam];"
```

Your string ends up evaluating with `...Regio.[Plaats]INNER JOIN ID.CSV...`. This lack of white space causes the sql parser to miss your second `INNER JOIN` .

Comment: I am afraid we're not there yet, again I get a missing operator message: [link](http://www.nedcom.nl/images/SQL%20Join%202020-04-07%20172031.jpg)

Comment: I forgot that JET SQL require you to use parentheses when doing multiple joins. I updated my answer, not quite sure if I got the parentheses in the right spot. Give it a try.

Comment: Ah, ThnX a million, that's it! I will certainly have to write that down somewhere!!!

Comment: Glad to help. Please consider accepting this answer if it help you :-)